# How do we catch an error in an "a, b, c, d" only input in c# console application?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, console-application

Suppose I have a collection of questions that can only be answered by a, b, c, and d.
How do we catch an exception if the user inputs a number or something that is out of the selection like w, q, r?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not catching an error. You're validating user input.

Comment: what have you [***tried yourself***](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please [edit] your question to include more information. also: i find it hard to believe you have _serious_ troubles in checking whether or not a string is "a", "b", "c" or "d".

Answer (score 1):

You can process inputs of this kind with a [switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_switch.php):

```cs
switch (input.ToLowerInvariant())
{
    case "a":
        //TODO: Process a
        break;
    case "b":
        //TODO: Process b
        break;
    case "c":
        //TODO: Process c
        break;
    case "d":
        //TODO: Process d
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Input was incorrect. Expected: a, b, c or d");
        break;
}
```

This is useful if different things have to be done depending on the different inputs.

If you only want to validate the inputs, you can create an array of valid inputs and check:

```cs
input = input.ToLowerInvariant();
string[] validAnswers = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
if (validAnswers.Contains(input))
{
    //TODO: Process input
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Input was incorrect. Expected: a, b, c or d");
}
```

But there are many ways to do this. You can simply check the input in an if-statement

```cs
if (input == "a" || input == "b" || input == "c" || input == "d") ...
```

or by using pattern matching

```cs
if (input is "a" or "b" or "c" or "d") ...
```

or by doing a character comparison:

```cs
if (input.Length == 1 && input[0] >= 'a' && input[0] <= 'd') ...
```